# C# unable to modify variables from event

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, unity-game-engine

I am working with C# in Unity 5. I ported some TCP code over from an app I built using .NET 4.5, based heavily on this:

[Asynchronous Socket Communication](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1608/Asynchronous-socket-communication)

I am unable to call any methods upon receiving data in the server app.

I receive TCP communication on an event:

```
public void OnReceivedData(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    SocketChatClient client = (SocketChatClient)ar.AsyncState;
    byte[] aryRet = client.GetRecievedData(ar);

    string aryRetString = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(aryRet);
    ParseCommand(aryRetString);

    if (aryRet.Length < 1)
    {
        client.Sock.Close();
        tcpClients.Remove(client);
        return;
    }
    client.SetupReceiveCallback(this);
}
```

ParseCommand() is very simple (for testing):

```
private void ParseCommand(string cmdToParse)
    {
        string[] splitInput = cmdToParse.Split(',');
        testValue++;
        Debug.Log(testValue.ToString());

        int playerStation = 0;
    }
```

When I use Debug.Log() to output the test value class variable to the console from with ParseCommand, it increments properly each time I call ParseCommand. However, if I continuously output testValue outside of ParseCommand, it never increments. Also, if I call a method inside of ParseCommand, the method does not fire, and it behaves as though it has exceptioned although no exception is thrown -- i.e., the method stops on that line and the calling method will not fire again.

Comment: Does `GetRecievedData` call the `EndReceive` method on an instance of the `Socket` class?

Comment: If it does, then try placing that call to `EndReceive` in a `try/catch` block and see if any exceptions are caught. You can find an example here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bew39x2a(v=vs.110).aspx. Take a look at the `ReceiveCallback` method.

Comment: There is an EndReceive call in a try/catch, and no exceptions are caught. I am receiving the data fine. What's odd is that I cannot manipulate class variables ... if for instance I were to create a bool in the class, set it to true by default, and set it to false in ParseCommand(), it would read false inside of ParseCommand() but still read true outside of ParseCommand().

Comment: Just tried another experiment ... instead of calling ParseCommand() inside of OnReceivedData(), I added the string of data to a generic list. In Update () (so on every frame) I looked for the length of the list; if it was > 0, I processed the command with ParseCommand(). This yielded the same result ... inside OnReceivedData() after adding to the list, the list reported the correct count. But in Update(), the list always reported a count of 0.

Comment: are you on the wrong thread?  Unity is ABSOLUTELY NOT MULTITHREADED IN ANY WAY, THERE IS ONLY ONE THREAD.  this often catches out seasoned programmers who are new to Unity.

Comment: No, this is all handled on a single thread. I've actually dealt with multithreading in Unity for a couple of production applications. Just so you're aware, while MonoBehaviour is not thread-safe, multithreading can be done in Unity; this is similar to how I've done it before: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/357033/unity3d-and-c-coroutines-vs-threading.html You just have to find ways to not involve the Unity API basically.

Comment: I ran an example in Unity with a class that runs an async operation using the `BeginInvoke` and `EndInvoke` methods of an `Action` delegate and it worked as expected. At the start the member variable was `true`. I invoked the async op from `Update` which set it to `false` and when the `Update` method displayed the variable in the debug window it was still `false`.

Comment: I believe Unity is multi-threaded in that its possible to run your own threads, but there could be issues if you try to interact with game objects, components, etc, from those threads.

Comment: Instead of using a separate class I ran the async operation from with the actual component and it works as before. The `ManagedThreadId` is different for both threads and the main thread has `IsBackground` set to `false` and the callback has it set of `true`. If you try to interact with the game object while on the background thread, then you get an exception. As for the problem your facing I can't seem to replicate it. Bare in mind I'm not using the `Socket` class. Just plain-old `Action` delegates.